# Python and Z3: integers and floating, how to manage them in the correct way?

Tags: python, z3

need help with Z3 and Python...it looks I'm too dumb for this. My code:

```
from z3 import *

num1 = Int('num1')
num2 = Int('num2')
num3 = Int('num3')

s = Solver()
s.add( 2 * num1 - num2 + 0.5 * num3 == 5412.0)
s.add( 2 * num1 + 3 * num2 + 4 * num3 == 28312.0)
```

The result is the following:

`[num3 = 1, num1 = 5568, num2 = 5724]`

Which is not completely correct: the first expression actually returns 5412.5, not 5412.0.
I guess it has to do with the mixed usage of "Int" with some "point numbers" (0.5).
I actually need to keep the "numX" as "Int", since they are integers (this is a constraint).
I guess I'm missing how to manage this mixed situation. Someone can help me?

Thanks,

**Edited**

Thanks to "alias" answer I got the right direction:

adding

`cc1 = RealVal(0.5)`

and then using that constant in the expression, I got the correct result.

Thanks to all!

Comment: You probably could have solved it also by multiplying every constant in the first linear equation by 2.

Comment: That's a cute trick to use `cc1`, forcing Python to move to `Real` for the expressions. But I think it's still quite dangerous to do such things, as you're relying on implicit conversions to do the "right" thing for you. It does the right thing in this case, but I think relying on this can lead to really hard-to-debug and complicated problems down the road. I'd recommend not mixing-and-matching types like this at all, but doing all the coversions yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're absolutely correct that Python bindings to Z3 suffer from weakly typing. This comes back to bite quite often, when least expected.

In these cases, `sexpr()` method is your friend. Add `print s.sexpr()` to the end of your program. It prints the following:

```
(declare-fun num3 () Int)
(declare-fun num2 () Int)
(declare-fun num1 () Int)
(assert (= (+ (- (* 2 num1) num2) (* 0 num3)) 5412))
(assert (= (+ (* 2 num1) (* 3 num2) (* 4 num3)) 28312))
```

And you can see your `0.5` became `0`! Which is totally not what you wanted. Welcome to the world of "I'll coerce to make things fit behind your back."

To solve this, you really need to be very clear on conversions. Z3 supports floating-point and also real numbers. (i.e., with infinite precision.) And arithmetic doesn't mix-and-match in the SMTLib land, so you have to be very careful on how you construct the proper constants.

Comment: I am struggling with a similar issue. Is there any general fix for this now? or do I need to move to Real variables?

Comment: You cannot mix/match different types in SMTLib, and Python bindings still do "implicit" conversions. So, you either have to always use the same underlying type (`Real` most likely), or be very explicit with conversions. Nothing changed with regard to this in the last two years when this answer was first written.

Answer (score 0):

`Int` declares (mathematical) integers, nothing else, so the model value will always be an integer. The expression `0.5 * num3` is automatically converted to integers (there's an option to disable these automatic conversions and instead throw an error). If you need fractional values, use `Real` instead of `Int`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The point is that, the results must be integers, that's why I can't switch to real. Is there any way to "cast" some specific operation (like the multiplication with 0.5) to real, but keep the results as Int?

Comment: @cips have you managed to find the answer for this? how to keep result as int.